# Grayscale conversion algortihm

Tags: image-processing

I am looking for a color to grayscale image conversion algorithm that ensures color contrast will be highly maintained after the conversion. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: What is the purpose of this? What do your images look like - do you have examples?

Comment: The purpose is to pass the images to a video tracking algorithm, thus contrast plays a critical role. Standard grayscale conversion tends to reduce contrast, especially for light shaded colors

Comment: Not sure I understand. If colour plays a critical role, why not use a colour-sensitive video tracker?

Comment: Because of the algorithm runs on an embedded device with very little processing power

Comment: Whatever the transformation, a large number of colors (like 256²) will map to the same grayscale value, which means that all contrast is lost. There is no escape.

Comment: It’s very hard to say without seeing any images or knowing the context, I guess you could convert to HSL and use the Hue channel as your grey. Typically you could consider using PCA to reduce dimensionality but if your hardware is low-powered... Another option might be filtration over the camera lens to help separate colours, or changing the lighting, or background.